# Looping over an Ember.js promise

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I am trying to loop over what I believe to be an Ember promise, but all I can seem to get returned is an object, when it should be an array.

jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qakine/1/edit

If I just loop over the items in the template then I have no issues, but I want to be able to interact with the array items in my controller. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a few things here, let me see if I can remember them all:

When you have a route under a resource, the routes and controllers of that route should take their parent's name.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("parent", function(){
    this.route("child");
  });
});

App.ParentChildRoute...

App.ParentChildController...
```

Handlebars can't access normal functions from your controller, this should be converted into a computed property.

```
App.ParentChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  middleNames: function(){
    ...
  }.property('middles.[]')
});
```

naming is case sensitive

```
{{#each name in middlenames}}
```

should be

```
{{#each name in middleNames}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cowibi/1/edit

Comment: Where did you learn .property('middles.[]')? I can't seem to find any documentation on it here: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: Oh, I managed to find the answer here:http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property__

Answer (score 0):

I created an new example based on yours to make things clear. You can check it out here:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hokabe/4/edit

For Ember route's `model` hook, if the return value is a promise, the route will wait for the promise resolved and pass the resolved value to controller's `model` property.

And a `App.Parent` instance's `middles` property returns a promise (actually it's a `DS.PromiseArray` instance) which will resolve a middles array (actually it's a `DS.ManyArray` instance).

so for getting children you can simply do this:

```
App.ParentMiddlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('parent').get('middles');
  }
});
```

Note that `modelFor` argument is a route name but not a model name. It means "Get the model from given route".